# Is JavaScript Source Mapping affected when running Chrome in Incognito Mode?

Tags: javascript, less, incognito-mode

I've got a simple .NET web app that renders slightly differently when running Chrome in Incognito mode. Most of the posts I've seen about this issue indicate that it is probably due to browser caching, but I've cleared the cache and re-opened and I don't think that's the issue.

Here are the normal and incognito mode examples, respectively. The first one is correct.

[image: Chrome in normal mode displays correctly.]

[image: Chrome in Incognito mode does not display correctly.]

Using Dev Tools >> Sources on normal-mode Chrome, I notice that there is a /Content/*less* folder, and that some of the html elements refer to those *.less* stylesheets (like *labels.less*, for example.)

In Incognito mode, however, there is no such folder.  What is happening in Incognito Mode that causes the *.less* files to not be rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer to this is No.  The issue was introduced when I added T4MVC to my project.  Incognito mode had nothing to do with it.

[Found this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13729854/2701313) that I think is the solution to my problem.  I haven't verified it yet, but I'm pretty confident that's the issue. If I get time to fix my code and check, I'll post an update.